# Testing a trigger click from a Backbone.View which opens a new Backbone.View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine, marionette

I have two Backbone Views, `MainView` and `PopupView`.

MainView contains a help button. When the help button handler is fired it shows the Backbone.View.

My question is how should I test this behavior from the `MainView` module?

---

Here's my code about `MainView`:

```
var MainView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click #help' : 'showPopUp'
    },

    showPopUp: function() {
       var popupView = new PopupView();
       app.vent.trigger('showModal', popupView);
    }    
});
```

---

Here's my code about the mainView.spec:

```
describe("When help button handler fired", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        this.view.render();
        this.view.$el.find('#help').trigger('click');
    });
    it("shows the popup", function() {
        // what should I do?
    });
});
```

---

Here's my code about the app:

```
var app = new Marionette.Application();

app.addRegions({
    header: '#header',
    sidebar: '#sidebar',
    main: '#main',
    modal: '#modal'
});

app.vent.on('showModal', function(view) {
    var modal = app.modal;

    modal.show(view);
    modal.$el.modal({
        show: true,
        keyboard: true,
        backdrop: 'static'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Sinon and Chai, you can try this:

```
describe("When help button handler fired", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
      this.popupSpy = sinon.spy()
      app.vent.on('showModal', this.popupSpy);
      this.view.render();
      this.view.$el.find('#help').trigger('click');
  });
  it("shows the popup", function() {
      this.popupSpy.callCount.should.equal(1);
      this.popupSpy.args[0][0].should.be.an.instanceOf(PopupView);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. `this.popupSpy.callCount.should.equal(1)` works; I am not sure about `this.popupSpy.args[0].should.be.an.instanceOf(PopupView);`. Actually `this.popupSpy.args[0].instanceof` is undefined. Any idea?

Comment: I get the following error `Object [object Object] has no method 'instanceOf. Anyway `this.popupSpy.callCount.should.equal(1)` should be `expect(this.popupSpy.callCount).toBe(1)` and `this.popupSpy.args[0][0].should.be.an.instanceOf(PopupView)` should be `expect(this.popupSpy.args[0][0]).instanceOf(this.view)`

Comment: My syntax works for mocha and chai, but yours looks about right for jasmine. They should be functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

So your Main View shouldn't open the popup, it shouldn't not even know that something like this exist. It should just notify the other modules via the eventbus that an popup should open by firing the event.

As you use `app.vent` I assume you're using marionette. In my project I have a Marionette.Region to handle an overlay view. And this region should open/close the view.

Doing it this way, its much easier to test. In the main view you can spy on the `app.vent` function and test that it will be execute when the button is clicked. In your region you can fire the event on `app.vent` and spy on your `view.render` function.

Creating new instances in your object you wanna test, makes testing always harder as it should be. Sure its easier in JavaScript, as in Java for example, cause you can override existing function on runtime in JavaScript, but using some way of dependency injection makes it always easier to mock and spy the dependencies.

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes you are right saying I am using `marionette`. I updated my question with code about the app with the `Marionette.Region`. Said that, it is not clear to me how should I spy the `view.render` in my spec. any ideas? thanks.

Comment: You can pass the view into the constructor of the region, so you can a pass a spy in your test. Or you can spy on the constructor (https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Spies) of your view and return a spy.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
describe("When help button handler fired", function() {
    var popupShown;

    beforeEach(function() {
        popupShown = false;

        this.view.render();
        app.vent.on('showModal', function() {
            popupShown = true;      
        });
        this.view.$el.find('#help').trigger('click');
    });
    it("shows the popup", function() {
        expect(popupShown).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

That said, I would recommend a few things:

1. As was mentioned elsewhere, don't create the modal view in MainView.  This couples the two too tightly.
2. In your tests, you may want to say something like `it("triggers the help event")` or something similar.  This is particularly important since you're unit testing that object in isolation.  For integration testing, the opposite would be true.
3. I'm not sure that you aren't doing too much in your `beforeEach` function. You may want to at least trigger the button click in the `it` scope, although based on what you're `describe`ing, this may be OK.